# Vert.x - Get parameters from POST request

Tags: java, rest, post, vert.x

Im trying to create a Vert.x Rest service that responds to POST requests on some URL\analysis.

Using the following command

> curl -D- http://localhost:8080\analyze -d '{"text":"bla"}'

I want to extract "bla" from the command and perform simple text analysis on it.:

Here is the draft of my code:

```
    @Override
public void start(Future<Void> fut) throws Exception {

    router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.post("/analyze").handler(this::analyze);

    // Create Http server and pass the 'accept' method to the request handler
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).
            listen(config().getInteger("http.port", 9000),
                    result -> {
                        if (result.succeeded()) {
                            System.out.println("Http server completed..");
                            fut.complete();
                        } else {
                            fut.fail(result.cause());
                            System.out.println("Http server failed..");
                        }
                    }
            );
}


private void analyze(RoutingContext context) {
    HttpServerResponse response = context.response();
    String bodyAsString = context.getBodyAsString();
    JsonObject body = context.getBodyAsJson();

    if (body == null){
        response.end("The Json body is null. Please recheck.." + System.lineSeparator());
    }
    else
    {
        String postedText = body.getString("text");
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        response.putHeader("content-type", "text/html");
        response.end("you posted json which contains the following " + postedText);
    }

}
```

}

Do you know how can I get the "bla" from POST?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following router and handler:

```
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
// add a handler which sets the request body on the RoutingContext.
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
// expose a POST method endpoint on the URI: /analyze
router.post("/analyze").handler(this::analyze);

// handle anything POSTed to /analyze
public void analyze(RoutingContext context) {
    // the POSTed content is available in context.getBodyAsJson()
    JsonObject body = context.getBodyAsJson();

    // a JsonObject wraps a map and it exposes type-aware getters
    String postedText = body.getString("text");

    context.response().end("You POSTed JSON which contains a text attribute with the value: " + postedText);
}
```

With the above code in place this CURL command ...

```
curl -D- http://localhost:9000/analyze -d '{"text":"bla"}'
```

... will return:

```
$ curl -D- http://localhost:9000/analyze -d '{"text":"bla"}'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 67
Set-Cookie: vertx-web.session=21ff020c9afa5ec9fd5948acf64c5a85; Path=/

You POSTed JSON which contains a text attribute with the value: bla
```

Looking at your question you have defined an endpoint named `/analyze` but then you suggested this CURL command: `curl -D- http://localhost:8080 -d '{"text":"bla"}'` which doesn't talk to the `/analyze` endpoint. Perhaps that's part of the issue or maybe that's just a typo when preparing the question. Regardless, the code I have supplied above will:

- Define an endpoint at `http://localhost:9000/analyze`
- Handle content POSTed to that endpoint

Comment: I fixed the typo. Regarding your solution, I get the Json object null, so I do not get the response as you said I would.
I also did not understand why you added "api" to the URL, as you said my endpoint was 'analyze'.

Comment: Could you update your original question to include the updated code, showing what you tried when you attempted to use my solution.  Re the inclusion of "api" that's an error on my part, I'll update the answer

Comment: @user2953423 I have updated the answer to add this piece: `router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());` this provides your webserver with a handler which sets the request body on the RoutingContext so that you can retrieve it with `context.getBodyXXX()`